# getopt is not working for one of my parameters

Tags: c, getopt

I have to programm a TCP/UDP Server/Client software.

Possible arguments: -u: UDP   -t: TCP     -l Server    -p: [Port]  -h [IP]

I wrote a function printflags, to see if everything works fine.
The u-, t-, l- and p-Options work fine. But my IP is everytime NULL. 
Where is the problem?

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int printflags(int, int, int, char *,char *); 

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){

    int uflag=0;
    int tflag=0;
    int lflag=0;
    char *pvalue = NULL;
    char *hvalue = NULL;
    int c;

    opterr = 0;

    while((c = getopt (argc, argv, "utlhp:")) != -1)
    {
        switch(c)
        {
        case 'u':
            uflag = 1;
            break;
        case 't':
            tflag = 1;
            break;
        case 'l':
            lflag = 1;
            break;
        case 'p':
            pvalue = optarg;
            break;
        case 'h':
            hvalue = optarg;
            break;
        case ':':
            fprintf(stderr, "case :");
        case '?':
            if(optopt == 'p' || optopt == 'h')
                fprintf(stderr, "Option '-%c' requires an argument.\n", optopt);
            else if (isprint(optopt))
                fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option character '-%c'.\n", optopt);
            else
                fprintf(stderr, "Unknown option character '%x'.\n", optopt);
            return 1;
        default:
             abort(); 
        }
     }
     printflags(uflag, tflag, lflag, pvalue, hvalue);
     return 0;
 }

int printflags(int uflag, int tflag, int lflag, char* pv, char *hv){
    printf("-u UDP: %d\n", uflag);
    printf("-t TCP: %d\n", tflag);
    printf("-l Listen Socket - Server: %d\n", lflag);   
     printf("-p Port: %s\n", pv);
     printf("-h IP: %s\n", hv);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: What input are you using?

Comment: ./programname -u -p 51930 -h 192.168.2.1

Answer (score 6):

Your option string should be `"utlh:p:"`. You need a colon after each letter that takes an optarg.

Answer (score 5):

Your parameter to [getopt()](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/getopt.html) needs a colon after the h to signify that -h needs an argument.

```
while((c = getopt (argc, argv, "utlh:p:")) != -1)
//                                  ^ --- here
```